# Nomenclature for the function appearing in Carathéodory's criteria of differentiability

Tags: derivatives, terminology

In my previous question [Concerning Carathéodory's criteria of differentiability and a proof that differentiable implies continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/487806/36530) I stated the criteria as follows:

> There exists a function $\phi$ which is continuous at $a$ with $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}\phi(x)=\phi(a)=N$ and $f(x)=f(a)+\phi(x)(x-a)$ for $x \neq a$.

I proved in the linked question that this criteria is equivalent to saying $f$ is differentiable at $x=a$ and $f'(a)=N$.

My question now is fairly simple:

> Is there an accepted (common) name for $\phi$ as it appears in the criteria above?

I'm tempted to call it the **difference quotient function of $f$ based at $x=a$** but this seems rather clumsy and I'm open to suggestions. For one non-example, I noticed in Remmert's *Theory of Complex Functions* he uses $f_c$ in place of $\phi$ for the complex analog 
(pg. 57 of Springer vol. 122), but, I see no name given to $f_c$ there.

Comment: It is called a slope function near the beginning of the second page in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259998808_Acosta_Delgado_Frechet_vs_Caratheodory) excellent article.

Answer (score 0):

It shall be called the **difference quotient** in my writings. I am of course still interested in the answer of others who have something to add.