# Complex differentiability Taylor formula

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits

In our lecture notes for an undergraduate course on complex analysis, we have the following:

> Let $D$ be a non-empty, open subset of $\mathbb{C}$.
>
> A function $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is said to be *complex
>   differentiable* at $z_0 \in D$ if the limit
>
> $$f'(z_0) = \lim_{z \rightarrow z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$$
>
> exists. We note that $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is complex
>   differentiable at $z_0 \in D$ with $f'(z_0) = a$ if and only if there
>   exists a function $g:D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that
>
> $$f(z) = f(z_0) + a(z-z_0) + |z-z_0|g(z)$$
>
> and $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0}g(z) = 0.$

I don't understand how the part following on from "We note that" follows. Can anyone provide an insight? Am I missing something easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative exists iff
$$ a = \lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}, $$
or
$$ 0 = \lim_{z \to z_0} \left( \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}-a \right), $$
or
$$ 0 = \lim_{z \to z_0}  \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)-a(z-z_0)}{z-z_0}, $$
which is equivalent to
$$ 0 = \lim_{z \to z_0} \left| \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)-a(z-z_0)}{z-z_0} \right|  $$
or
$$ 0 = \lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)-a(z-z_0)}{\lvert z-z_0 \rvert}  \tag{1} $$
(where the absolute value functions go doesn't matter for complex limits that are zero).
If we define
$$ g(z) = \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)-a(z-z_0)}{\lvert z-z_0 \rvert} \quad (z \neq z_0), $$
we see that $(1)$ is equivalent to asking that $\lim_{z \to z_0} g(z) = 0$.

This is the notion that the derivative provides the best linear approximation to the function at a point. This form is useful for proving properties of derivatives that look like they require dividing by zero (the chain rule being a good example).

Comment: I believe the existence of the $g(z)$ with all the bells and whistles so described is known as the Caratheodory criterion. For example, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/487806/36530