# Differentiating under the Integral with Carathéodory.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

Let $f(x, y)$ be a real valued function defined on the real domain $X \times Y$ which is integrable in the Riemann or Lebesgue sense (or any other ?) on this domain.
Further, let the partial derivative $\frac {\partial{f(x, y)}} {\partial{y}}$ be defined throughout the domain.
We want to show that $\frac {\partial{\int f(x, y)} dx} {\partial{y}} =\int \frac {\partial{f(x, y)}} {\partial{y}} dx$ for all $y \in Y$.
**I'd appreciate feedback on my proof attempt which follows**...........

---

Take the Carathéodory definition of differentiability (see e.g. [Concerning Carathéodory's criteria of differentiability and a proof that differentiable implies continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/487806) ), clearly equivalent to the usual definition.
By this definition, $\frac {\partial{f(x, y)}} {\partial{y}}$ is defined throughout the domain means that for all $x, y, y_0$ in the domain there is a function $\psi$ such that $f(x, y) = f(x, y_0) + (y - y_0)\psi(x, y)$ where $\psi(x, y)$ is continuous at $y_0$ and then $\frac {\partial{f(x, y)}} {\partial{y}}|_{y_0} = \psi(x, y_0)$.

Since $f$ is integrable then $\int{f(x, y)}dx = \int{f(x, y_0)} + (y - y_0)\psi(x, y) dx $
And, $f(x, y_0)$ is x-integrable too, so $(y - y_0)\psi(x, y)$ is x-integrable and
$\int (y - y_0)\psi(x, y)dx   = \int{f(x, y)}dx - \int{f(x, y_0)} dx= (y - y_0)\int \psi(x, y)dx$

So,   $\int{f(x, y)}dx = \int{f(x, y_0)}dx + (y - y_0) \int \psi(x, y) dx $
Then provided $\int \psi(x, y) dx $  is continuous at $y = y_0$ for all $y_0$ this is the Carathéodory definition that $\int{f(x, y)}dx $ is y-differentiable at $y_0$ and that $\frac {\partial{\int f(x, y)} dx} {\partial{y}}|_{y_0} = \int \psi(x, y_0) dx  =\int \frac {\partial{f(x, y)}} {\partial{y}}|_{y=0} dx$ for all $y_0 \in Y$.

**But I don't see how to prove continuity ?**

Comment: To make sure I understood: you want to establish continuity of $\int_X \psi(x,y)dx $ as a function of $y$? If $y_0$ has a compact neighbourhood then I think you should be able to do this using continuity of $\psi$ and DCT.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Yes, continuity as you understand it.

Comment: You will not be able to prove continuity of $\int \psi$ (resp. differentiability of $\int f$) without additional assumptions. You can try to  construct a counter example by looking at something that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRzmr.png) (excuse the bad drawing, I did it on a trackpad) in $(-1,1)\times (0,1)$ for small $y$.

Comment: @s.harp But we know from other proofs that $\int{f(x, y)}dx $ is y-differentiable at $y_0$ and so by the Carathéodory definition $\int \psi(x, y) dx $  must be continuous at $y_0$ ?

Comment: You need some kind of regularity of $y$ variable. Like an integrable majorant $h: X\to\Bbb R$ with $|\partial_y f(x,y)| ≤ h(x)$ for almost all $x,y$.

Comment: @s.harp yes, I see that other proofs also have conditions I didn't notice before. Thanks.